# Why probability converges to 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

There is sequence of sets $\{A_n\}_{n \to \infty}$. It converges to $\emptyset$.

Why will the probability of sets converge to $0$, if $P(\emptyset) = 0$?

Comment: What do you mean by convergence of sets ?

Answer (score 0):

Working with the complements $B_n = \Omega \setminus A_n$, you get to the case of an sequence of sets $(B_n)$ that increases and converges to the full set $\Omega$.
You need to use $\sigma$-additivity now : You decompose the set $\Omega$ as the following disjoint union $\Omega = \bigcup\limits_n B_{n+1} \setminus B_n$. So, $\sigma$-additivity tells you that $1= P(\Omega) = \sum\limits_n P(B_{n+1})-P(B_n)$. Now, you notice that this sum is the limit of the partial sums $\sum\limits_{n\leq N} P(B_{n+1})-P(B_n) = P(B_{N+1})$ as $N$ tends to infinity. This means exactly that $P(B_{N+1}) \rightarrow 1$ as $N$ tends to infinity. Now, taking complements again, and recalling that $P(A_N)=1-P(B_N)$, you get : $P(A_N) \rightarrow 0 $ as $N$ tends to infinity.

Comment: $A_n$ need not be monotonically decreasing sequence converging to $\phi$.